# grep error in perl

Tags: perl

Newbie to perl. I am trying to grep from the values of a hash array. Can someone explain why I get uninitialized value error when i try

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %families = (Flintstone => [ qw(Pebbles)                    ],
            Simpson    => [ qw(Bart Lisa Maggie)           ],
            Keaton     => [ qw(Alex Mallory Jennifer Andy) ]);
my $user = 'Mary';
foreach my $name (keys %families)
{
    print "$name has @{$families{$name}} \n";

    if (grep /$user/,@{families{$name}})
    {
    print "User $user found \n"
    }
    else
    {
    print "User $user not found";
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Thank you. I fixed $name. However grep doesnt seem to work for me. i.e if I change $user to Bart I still get User Bart not found.

Comment: Never, ever abbreviate or summarize errors when asking questions. Copy and paste, always.

Comment: Thanks to indent your code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean

```
@{$families{$name}}
```

Instead of

```
@{families{name}}
```

Perhaps?

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error. However the logic doesnt seem to work especially the grep part.. For eg if I change $user to Bart, still I get User Bart not found

Comment: @user1719051 You're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice you get the error on line 13 but not on line 11?  The missing $ may be important.